# Output of Anonymous Thread class is not synchronized

Tags: java, multithreading

I have the following code snippet.

```
public class Test {
     static final StringBuffer sb1 = new StringBuffer();  
     static final StringBuffer sb2 = new StringBuffer();  
     public static void main(String args[])  
     {  
        new Thread()  
        {  
           public void run()  {  
            synchronized(this)  
            {  
                try {
                sb1.append("A");  
                sb2.append("B"); 
                System.out.println (sb1 + " " + sb2);   
                Thread.currentThread().sleep(5000);  
                    h.sb1.append("U"); 
                    h.sb2.append("V");
                    System.out.println (sb1 + " " + sb2);  
                 } catch (InterruptedException e) {  
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
                    e.printStackTrace();  
                }
            }  
           }  
        }.start();   
        new Thread() 
        { 
        public void run() 
        { 
            synchronized(this) 
            { 
                sb1.append("C"); 
                sb2.append("D"); 
                System.out.println (sb1 + " " + sb2);  
            } 
        }  
    }.start(); /* Line 28 */

    new Thread() 
        { 
        public void run() 
        { 
            synchronized(this) 
            { 
                sb1.append("E"); 
                sb2.append("F"); 
                System.out.println (sb1 + " " + sb2);
            } 
        }  
    }.start();  

    }
}
```

And when I run the program looks like it is not synchronized at object level. The output I'm getting is:

```
A B
AC BD
ACE BDF
ACEU BDFV
```

And I'm expecting the expected output as

```
A B
AU BV
AUC BVD
AUCE BVDF
```

Can someone please clarify what does this keyword refer to? Also if I use `synchronize(this.getThreadGroup())` instead of `synchronized(this)`. I get the output the expected output.

Comment: What is `h` in `h.sb1`?

Comment: run your code, and got your expected output, sleep() function doesn't release the lock, so the code should work as expected

Comment: I saw you use synchronized(sb1) insteadof synchronized(this)

Comment: There's a chance one of the other threads (C/D or E/F) could start first, but that wouldn't explain the output you are seeing.  Your code (with "h" removed) works for me as expected.

Comment: I don't trust you anymore.

Comment: h is the instance of the Test class and in my initial post I have used synchronized(this) not synchronized(sb1). I deliberately used sleep() method to check if it holds the lock. But it is not.

Comment: you are getting locks on `h` and `this`. That's misleading it. Put `h.sb1.append("U"); 
                    h.sb2.append("V");` in `synchronized(h)` block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
synchronized(this)
```

can't work in this case, since `this` would refer to the `Thread` object and every `run` function is running in the own Thread.

if you use `synchronized(sb1)` your code should work as intended. You can synchronize on every object you want, java will lock the object on the statement and release it after the brackets. You should simply care, that you really synchronize on the same object.